# Linux Module descriptions missing

Tags: linux, kernel, kernel-modules

I am relatively new to Linux and I was reading a book for LPIC-1. Reading the module part I was checking my modules and noticed that some modules don't have a description.

**ac97_bus, autofs4, cdrom, crc32_pclmul, crypto_simd, glue_helper, hid, jbd2, sunrpc, usb_common, usbcore**

I tried Google but I didn't find any answer there, or on this site either.

So, can you tell me why those modules don't have a description?

Best regards,

me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not mandatory for a Linux kernel module to have a description filled in. If one does have it, you can find it in the module source code as a `MODULE_DESCRIPTION` declaration like [this](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/latest/source/sound/pci/hda/hda_intel.c#L245):

```
MODULE_DESCRIPTION("Intel HDA driver");
```

which you can inspect via `modinfo` on the .ko object:

```
$ modinfo snd_hda_intel
filename:       /lib/modules/5.3.0-40-generic/kernel/sound/pci/hda/snd-hda- 
intel.ko
description:    Intel HDA driver
license:        GPL
```

But to make it short - as that's just for documentation purposes, some modules simply don't have it.